# Qt Json выгрузка

Tags: qt, json, qt5

Есть JSON

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "meta": {
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

Код вывода:

```
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());    
QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonResponse.object();    
qDebug() << "Status:" << jsonObj["status"].toString();
qDebug() << "Count:" << jsonObj["meta"].toObject().find("count").value();
qDebug() << jsonObj.keys();
```

Получаемый результат:

```
Status: "ok"
Count: QJsonValue(double, 1)
("status", "meta")
```

Как правильно выгрузить count?

Comment: toString() не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
QJsonValue obj = jsonObj["meta"].toObject().find("count").value();
if(obj.isDouble()) {
    std::cout << obj.toDouble() << std::endl;
}
```

Если там что-то другое, можно в [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonvalue.html#toVariant) превратить.